# Check if excerpt is empty at loop-portfolio

Tags: functions, loop, permalinks, excerpt

I want to check if excerpt is not empty, then echo the excerpt link, if not the echo permalink, like this:

`if(the_excerpt()!='') echo the_excerpt(); else echo get_permalink()`
but how can I check if the excerpt field is empty without using the content when empty?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Solved it :) `if(get_the_content()!='') echo get_permalink(); else echo the_excerpt();`

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. You can always add your own solution as an answer, but this is not exactly a solution to the stated problem: *"check if excerpt is not empty"*. Please update the question accordingly to avoid confusion ;-) It looks like I misunderstood your question ;-) Notice you don't need the extra `echo` for `the_excerpt()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one , ..

```
     $ID = get_the_ID();
        $page_data = get_page( $ID );
        $excerp = strip_tags($page_data->post_excerpt);

if ( !empty( $excerp ) ) :
    the_excerpt();
else :
    echo get_permalink()
endif;
```

Comment: Aside from a missing `;`, you might want to explain why this would solve the question and why you want to add the permalink if the excerpt is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check excerpt via

```
if(has_excerpt()){
//do your stuff
}else{
//do your stuff
}
```